# Pixel location issue with version 12.3

Tags: front-end, version-12.3

I have recently noticed that the pixel rendering of version 12.3 may have problems, please check the picture below, obviously, it is shifted toward the upper left corner.
I am using Windows 10, when I changing windows display zoom from 100% to 125%, it looks normal, But my screen is not a high resolution screen, doesn't suit to change this setting.   Can you reproduce this problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't observe this with version 12.3.1 on Win 10 x64 both with 100% and 125% `Magnification` setting (display 1920x1080, Windows screen magnification setting is 125% (recommended), also tried switching it to 100% - everything is OK).

Comment: You should report this to support at wolfram.com.